# How can I manage microdata with xslt?

Tags: xslt, microdata

I'm trying to add a tag like

```
<div itemscope>
```

in my xslt transformation but I get an error.(The expected token is '=')

I'm working in C# .net 4.0 xslt 1.0.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

XSLT is optimized for generating XML output. HTML5 is, in general, not XML. The syntax

```
<div itemscope>
```

is clearly not XML and therefore can't be generated using `xsl:attribute`. This is because XML doesn't support empty-valued attributes. That's the bad news.

The good news: There are two ways of writing the same thing as `<div itemscope>` that are valid HTML5 *and* valid XML:

```
<div itemscope="">
<div itemscope="itemscope">
```

So pick your favorite and generate that!

Comment: This is correct +1. The fact that _HTML_ allows non-XML rules like attribute without values or attribute values without quotes does not mean that you MUST use them. When dealing with XSLT (I think even in other cases) you MUST use the corresponding markup alternatives specified in the W3C spec.

Comment: do you know if itemscope="itemscope" respond to my microdata problematic describe at : http://schema.org/Place ?

Comment: @Christophe: I'm afraid I don't quite understand the question. I'll repeat: `<div itemscope>` is equivalent to `<div itemscope="">` and equivalent to `<div itemscope="itemscope">`.

Comment: @Tomalak: No, you can't give it any value you like. `itemscope` is an HTML5 boolean attribute. This means the only allowed values are no value (`<div itemscope>`), the empty string (`<div itemscope="">`), and the name of the attribute itself (`<div itemscope="itemscope">`). Any other value is invalid HTML5.

Comment: The HTML serialization of HTML5 is not XML, but HTML5 has an alternative serialization as XML document: XHTML5. This laureate standard serialization is defined in the HTML5 specification. If you serve your document as XHTML5, you can benefit from the XML toolings like XSLT as well as using HTML5 standards like microdata.

Comment: when I use `itemscope` in blogger.com, the editor changes `itemscope` to `itemscope=""` after I switch from HTML edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<div itemscope>]]></xsl:text>
```

Comment: I'm avoiding this kind of trick... I try to respect the xslt logical, and standards. div is actually a node if I want to use xsl:attribute on it with your solution I cannot. but thanks.

Comment: XSL is XML-based language. "<div itemscope>" isn't well-formed XML.

Comment: I know but in order to make this http://schema.org/docs/gs.html there is no other solution than <xsl:text and cdata?

Comment: Isn't. Why you don't like this solution?

Comment: for two reasons : -first if I want to use xsl:attribute I can't. -Second I take the risk to forget to close this tag oppened by this way.

Comment: I wait some days if I don't have any others answers I really feel confortable with. I will accept yours

Comment: I agree with you. But using xsl:attribute you can construct only well-formed xml.