# Can I use Microdata with JSF 2.0?

Tags: jsf, microdata

I found this page:
http://www.kiwi-community.eu/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7733331

But it is rather discouraging.

Do I simply add the namespace and use the tags ?
I also seem to have a hard time finding the correct namespace...

Answer (score 1):

When adding microdata to a JSF composite component in a webapp I'm working on I found that it worked fine as long as itemscope was not left with an empty value. See: [how-can-i-manage-microdata-with-xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453405/how-can-i-manage-microdata-with-xslt)

So something like the following is fine:

```
<section itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <div class="profile">
        <h4 itemprop="name" ><h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.name}"/></h4>
        <h5 itemprop="title"><h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.jobTitle}"/></h5>
        <p itemprop="telephone" class="phone"><h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.phoneNumber}"/></p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

idk what jsf is but you can use microdata in any html5 markup. check out schema.org for the namespace and linkage dude.