# XSLT to create HTML5 with Microdata

Tags: xslt-2.0, microdata

I feel that using `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">` is a bit of a workaround.. my intuition tells me that I'm not doing it right if I have to disable output-escaping.

Desired output: `<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">` (note: this validates as acceptable HTML5).

Error message: **Description: Attribute name "itemscope" associated with an element type "div" must be followed by the ' = ' character.**

Successful workaround:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book"></xsl:text>
..content..
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/div></xsl:text>
```

Can I do this another (better) way? Should I declare a namespace or schema in the stylesheet?  (using XSLT 2.0)

**UPDATE**: Nevermind. I just found the answer here [How can I manage microdata with xslt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453405/how-can-i-manage-microdata-with-xslt)